# Query FTS table MIN

Tags: android, mysql, sql, sqlite, full-text-search

I'm trying to get the lowest `_id` from my fts table with this query:

```
SELECT MIN(_id) FROM fts WHERE tbl_no=2 AND parent_id=6
```

The result I'm getting is **10**. However the smallest `_id` is **9** and it fits the selection arguments.

If I instead use

```
SELECT _id FROM fts WHERE tbl_no=2 AND parent_id=6
```

and select the 1st row, I get the correct result: **9**.

Does have something to do with the table being virtual (FTS)? I recently transfered from multiple tables to a single FTS and am experiencing this.

Am I guaranteed to get the results I want with the 2nd query, considering the table never updated and it's sorted by default.

**Notes**: I am running this on Android (tried `rawQuery` and `query`). I have the table in front of me and I know it's correct:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `_id` a numeric or a string?

With string comparison, '10' < '9'.

Try:

```
SELECT MIN(CAST(_id AS UNSIGNED)) FROM fts WHERE tbl_no=2 AND parent_id=6
```

To check. I would not use this in production however as it won't be able to use an index.

Comment: The _id field was actually of type `text` and since you answered first I'll choose this as a correct answer. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

In FTS tables, all columns store string values, and the string `'10'` is lexicographically smaller than `'9'`.

Furthermore, `MIN(SomeColumn)` is not a full-text search query, and thus is not very efficient.

For a unique integer ID in FTS tables, you should use the [internal `docid` column](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_1_3).

Comment: Well I've ran some tests, and it looks like FTS *can* store ints as well as strings. It seems to be defined implicitly.

Comment: Just because it's a FTS table, doesn't preclude having another index on a column. `MIN(SomeColumn)` should be lightning with a normal index.

Comment: You cannot add a normal index to a virtual table.